# jQuery wrap() is wrapping every assigned object on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that creates a div when you enter a name and click "add". I want to wrap this div in an li but when I do this it wraps every created div with the same class name in an li therefore I end up with multiple levels of li's around the div. Is there a way to only target the div that is created on that click?

The fiddle is here
http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/BMX4J/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMX4J/2/). All I've done is moved the creation of the new `div` outside of the call to `append`, and stored it in a variable so it can be reused. The relevant code from the fiddle:

```
var newDiv = $('<div class="div_menu_button"></div>');
$('#created_buttons').append(newDiv.val(value).text(value) );
newDiv.wrap("<li></li>");
```

Comment: Thanks man, thats just what I was looking for,. Thanks for explaining too, cheers